# How to abort a server action in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions

There is no mention in the documentation of how do I abort an action and how to handle the abortions.

Comment: Why not use try/catch within your server action and just throw an error when the function needs to be aborted?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following using next 14.1.4, but it may work with previous versions. In my case, I managed to abort the action by terminating the invocation of the action.

Example,

```
const delayWithAbort = async (ms: number, abortSignal: AbortSignal) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    if (abortSignal) {
      abortSignal.addEventListener('abort', () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        console.log('delayWithAbort was aborted');
        reject( new AbortError('Delay aborted'));
      })
    }
  });
};
```

My route

```
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    req.signal.onabort = () => {
      console.log('Browser/Proxy abruptly disconnected'); // just fyi
    };
    
    await delayWithAbort(4000, req.signal);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof AbortError) {
      return new Response('aborted', { status: 499 })
    }
    return new Response('error', {status: 500});
  }

  // happy path
  return Response.json({
    hello: "world",
    date: new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
      timeZone: "America/New_York",
    }),
  });
}

class AbortError extends Error {
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
    this.name = 'AbortError';
  }
}
```